# Anycubic Kossel Plus raises the Printhead around the corners of the bed too High if the print is too close to the corners

Tags: print-quality, nozzle, kossel

Hi guys I am quite new to 3D printing. I am having this problem with the printhead rising too high during printing when it gets near to the beds' borders. It isn't a problem with smaller prints but it gets very frustrating with bigger ones. I am thinking I am doing something wrong with the calibration but don't know exactly what. I am not calibrating by hand rather using auto calibrate.

[image]

I am using Cura 15.04.03 as slicer.

Comment: That doesn't look like the printhead lifting but warping...

Comment: I could put a video of it doing it. On the the picture i also got the excess material off so maybe thats why it looks like warping.

Comment: wait, you use cura (1.)15.04.03? You should seriously update to cura 4.X!

Answer (score 2):

It is a common  problem with "delta"-style circular parallel kinematics machines.  It is called Bowling.  It can lead to the presumed Z=0 plane having a bowl-like shape.  The actual error shape can be more complex.  The job of "bed-leveling" is to make the realized z=0 plane to be identical with the bed.

If you can, use a multi-point (like 40+ points) interpolation.  It builds an error map, and adjusts every point based on that map.